# React Native build error in Android: adb: error=86, Bad CPU type in executable

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I'm building the default React Native project after having just created it using `npx react-native init MyProject`. In Xcode with my iOS sim, it loads just fine. With Android (Android Studio) I'm getting a build error:

```
BUILD FAILED in 13s

Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
[adb]: Cannot run program "/Users/jasonmenayan/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=86, Bad CPU type in executable

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
```

(full stack trace at bottom)

It's seems there's some sort of compatibility, but I'm not sure which component(s) needs to be up-/downgraded.

Versions:

- React Native: `0.71.8`
- Java Runtime/server: `Corretto-11.0.19.7.1` (`openjdk version "11.0.19" 2023-04-18 LTS`)
- Android Studio: `Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2`
- MacOS: `Ventura 13.4`
- Macbook: `2019 Intel i9 chip`

Full build error & stack trace:

```
info Opening the app on Android...
info JS server already running.
info Launching emulator...
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:buildCodegenCLI SKIPPED
> Task :app:generateCodegenSchemaFromJavaScript SKIPPED
> Task :app:generateCodegenArtifactsFromSchema SKIPPED
> Task :app:generatePackageList
> Task :app:preBuild
> Task :app:preDebugBuild
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compressDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dexBuilderDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeProjectDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugApkListingFileRedirect UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:installDebug FAILED
38 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 36 up-to-date
[adb]: Cannot run program "/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=86, Bad CPU type in executable

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=86, Bad CPU type in executable

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s

Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
[adb]: Cannot run program "/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=86, Bad CPU type in executable

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=86, Bad CPU type in executable

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s

    at makeError (/Users/me/Desktop/terses/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/me/Desktop/terses/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/me/Desktop/terses/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/me/Desktop/terses/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:108:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```